# java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints , without changing jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2

Tags: java, http, https, ssl-certificate

Searching the reason of this

```
exception `"java.security.cert.CertificateException`" find out a lot of solution which suggests to change or revert jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms property on how was in Java 6.
```

I am wondering if is there any other way to resolve this issue without changing configurations.

Comment: In short - do not use MD2. It's completely broken. A collision can be generated using very trivial CPU power like a mobile phone.
I would recommend to check why you use such certificates.